# Is my method for Recursive division for my maze generator correct?

Tags: c#, recursion, maze

Im trying to make a maze generator using Recursive division explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

The first iteration works for me. But when I do it multiple times It doesnt do it properly.
Question is: Is my recursve method corrext? The if and else statements followed up with either a return or recusion.

```
private void DevideRecursive(int pMinX, int pMaxX, int pMinY, int pMaxY)   
{

    Debug.Log("minx: " + pMinX);
    Debug.Log("maxx: " + pMaxX);
    Debug.Log("miny: " + pMinY);
    Debug.Log("maxy: " + pMaxY);
    int randomX = Random.Range(pMinX +1, pMaxX);
    int randomY = Random.Range(pMinY +1, pMaxY);
    int randomWall = Random.Range(0, 4);

    List<GameObject> WalllistX1 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> WalllistX2 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> WalllistY1 = new List<GameObject>();
    List<GameObject> WalllistY2 = new List<GameObject>();

    List<List<GameObject>> MainWallList = new List<List<GameObject>>();
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistX1);
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistX2);
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistY1);
    MainWallList.Add(WalllistY2);

    //// add a wall on a random x coordinate
    for (int x = pMinX; x < pMaxX; x++)
    {
        GameObject wall = Instantiate(WallHor);
        wall.transform.position = new Vector2(tilesize * x + tilesize / 2, tilesize * randomY);
        if (x < randomX)
        {
            WalllistX1.Add(wall);
        }
        else
        {
            WalllistX2.Add(wall);
        }
    }
    //// add a wall on a random y coordinate
    for (int y = pMinY; y < pMaxY ; y++)
    {
        GameObject wall = Instantiate(WallVer);
        wall.transform.position = new Vector2(tilesize * randomX, tilesize * y + tilesize / 2);
        if (y < randomY)
        {
            WalllistY1.Add(wall);
        }
        else
        {
            WalllistY2.Add(wall);
        }
    }

    //make a hole in 3 out of tht 4 walls randomly
    for (int i = 0; i < MainWallList.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("list" + MainWallList.Count);
        if (randomWall != i)
        {
            Debug.Log("1: " + WalllistX1.Count);
            Debug.Log("2: " + WalllistX2.Count);
            Debug.Log("3: " + WalllistY1.Count);
            Debug.Log("4: " + WalllistY2.Count);
            RemoveWall(MainWallList[i]);
        }
    }

    ////
    ////
    //// If either of the walls have a cell with only 1 grid stop the recursion
    if (randomX - pMinX <= 1 || pMaxY - randomY <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DevideRecursive(pMinX, randomY, randomX, pMaxY);
    }

    if (pMaxX - randomX <= 1 || pMaxY - randomY <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DevideRecursive(randomY, pMaxX, randomX, pMaxY);
    }

    if (randomX - pMinX <= 1 || randomY - pMinY <=1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DevideRecursive(pMinX, randomY, pMinY, randomX);
    }

    if (pMaxX - randomX <= 1 || randomY - pMinY <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DevideRecursive(randomY, pMaxX, pMinY, randomX);
    }
}
```

what my code does(or is supposed to do). in a rectangular maze, build at random points two walls that are perpendicular to each other. These two walls divide the large chamber into four smaller chambers separated by four walls. Choose three of the four walls at random, and open a one cell-wide hole at a random point in each of the three. Continue in this manner recursively, until every chamber has a width of one cell in either of the two directions.

here is quick illustration of the frist iteration https://gyazo.com/08e1cb2483fcf841e4d854d001c51647

for example the next iteration is going to be in the upper left room. then minX stays the same. MaxX becomes the RandomX. the same for the Y values. then it should do the same again(creating 2 walls )

Comment: We can't tell, because we don't know what exactly this DevideRecursive methods is you are calling there (we can guess, but we cannot be certain unless you tell us exactly), what its arguments are, and what the order of those arguments in the DevideRecursive method signature is.

Comment: Also, why are you subtracting variables that have an X in the name from variables that have an Y in the name, and vice versa? Is this just an attempt to confuse everybody, or is there some hidden meaning behind you doing it that way?

Comment: sorry I just brainfarted and completely forgot to explain. I added the whole method now with some explanation. I hope this makes it clearly.(also changed the RandomX and RandomY)

Comment: lets the grid is 10 by 10

Comment: *"when I do it multiple times It doesnt do it properly. Question is: Is my recursve method corrext?"* Doesn't the first part of this statement answer the question? Trace the code in your debugger and after the first walls are placed, watch how the program state changes during the execution of each line. That should help uncover the problem, which should lead to a solution or a more specific question than *"why doesn't my code work?"*.

Comment: yes you are right, thats actually the main problem. I cant figure out how to stop my program at certain points.Im using it in unity. and since im not using it in an update loop I cant do like an if statement with a buttonpress. Any idea how to make this happen?